# Getting .html info from large file

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a `.html` file called `xConnect_LG.html`.

It contains a pretty large table with id's and text. Size is: `1955 Kb`.

What would be the most efficient way to read the first column in a large table?

I've tried `simple_html_dom`, but it seems that it only reads around 620 id's before it stops.

I have around 3000 id's in the table. What I did is this, `note I need another way`.

```
$html = file_get_html('../Test/reqID/xConnect_LG.html');
// $tables will be an array of all found tables
$tables = $html->find('table');
// you will need to also loop over all tables
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
      if (is_numeric($row->find('td',0)->plaintext)) {
          $reqIDs[] = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext; 
          echo $row->find('td',0)->plaintext . '<br>';
      }         
  } 
}
```

What would be the best tool for searching a .html file, and retrieve every , in alle the tables?

(yes i have more than one in the same `.html`)

Comment: Have you tried DOMDocument, it's a more standard library which may be able to cope with the HTML.

Comment: Do you have anything in your error logs? You might be hitting an execution time limit or a memory limit.

Comment: The file is too much large, why don't you just open it, iterate over it line by line, take only the id from each line and then close it, without loading it all in the memory

Comment: @SaymoinSam Do you have an example on how this should be done? It needs to basically take every first `<td>` inside the `<tr>`, because it's here the ID's is (first column in each table). And yes i also might think the file is too large.

Comment: You need to provide a piece of your file, so we can see its structure and how to implement that